# How to remove a pattern of text ending with a colon in R?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have the following sentence

```
review <- C("1a. How long did it take for you to receive a personalized response to an internet or email inquiry made to THIS dealership?: Approx. It was very prompt however. 2f. Consideration of your time and responsiveness to your requests.: Were a little bit pushy but excellent otherwise 2g. Your satisfaction with the process of coming to an agreement on pricing.: Were willing to try to bring the price to a level that was acceptable to me. Please provide any additional comments regarding your recent sales experience.: Abel is awesome! Took care of everything from welcoming me into the dealership to making sure I got the car I wanted (even the color)! ")
```

I want to remove everything before :

I tried the following code,

```
gsub("^[^:]+:","",review)
```

However, it only removed first sentence ending with a colon

Expected results:

```
Approx. It was very prompt however. Were a little bit pushy but excellent otherwise Were willing to try to bring the price to a level that was acceptable to me. Abel is awesome! Took care of everything from welcoming me into the dealership to making sure I got the car I wanted (even the color)!
```

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  everything before can include all the characters.  Is it a sentence?

Comment: So you just want to remove ``1a.``, ``2f.``, ``2g.``, ``:`` ? Are those characters the same on each rows?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, basically, I meant I want to get rid of all the questions in the sentence and just keep the responses. In my case, the questions are ending with a colon, that's why I mentioned everything before colon

Comment: Try `gsub("(?:\\d+[a-zA-Z]\\.)?[^.?!:]*[?!.]:\\s*", "", review)`

Comment: It would great if you could explain me the regex please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sentences are not complex and have no abbreviations you may use

```
gsub("(?:\\d+[a-zA-Z]\\.)?[^.?!:]*[?!.]:\\s*", "", review)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yev1gC/3).

Note that you may further generalize it a bit by changing `\\d+[a-zA-Z]` to `[0-9a-zA-Z]+` / `[[:alnum:]]+` to match 1+ digits or letters.

**Details**

- `(?:\d+[a-zA-Z]\.)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `[a-zA-Z]` - an ASCII letter
  - `\.` - a dot
- `[^.?!:]*` - 0 or more chars other than `.`, `?`, `!`, `:`
- `[?!.]` - a `?`, `!` or `.`
- `:` - a colon
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces

R test:

```
> gsub("(?:\\d+[a-zA-Z]\\.)?[^.?!:]*[?!.]:\\s*", "", review)
[1] "Approx. It was very prompt however. Were a little bit pushy but excellent otherwise Were willing to try to bring the price to a level that was acceptable to me.Abel is awesome! Took care of everything from welcoming me into the dealership to making sure I got the car I wanted (even the color)! "
```

**Extending to handle abbreviations**

You may enumerate the exceptions if you add alternation:

```
gsub("(?:\\d+[a-zA-Z]\\.)?(?:i\\.?e\\.|[^.?!:])*[?!.]:\\s*", "", review)     
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here, `(?:i\.?e\.|[^.?!:])*` matches 0 or more `ie.` or `i.e.` substrings or any chars other than `.`, `?`, `!` or `:`.

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/gRJHQ9/1).

Comment: For sentences such as "4c. Please rate the condition of your vehicle upon return to you (i.e. cleanliness, undamaged).: Thank you so much for the wash!", the regex does not return expected results. How do I go about this ?

Comment: @gamyanaidu I added that at the very start: *if there are no abbreviations*. If there are, you can add them manually, like `(?:\d+[a-zA-Z]\.)?(?:i\.?e\.|[^.?!:])*[?!.]:\s*`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/gRJHQ9/1).

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you very much.